# android:textIsSelectable not working - Gives me error

Tags: android, clipboardmanager

I am using this `android:textIsSelectable` and still gets the error: `TextView does not support text selection. Action mode cancelled.`

Can any one please tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

I am willing to bet that you are trying to use this attribute on an EditText. It is only for TextView, so you cannot use it in an EditText.

Comment: Well, you didn't specify and this error is common for EditTexts. An EditText extends TextView, so just the error saying "TextView does not support text selection" is not enough to go by.

Comment: "TextView does not support text selection" doesn't say "EditView", it says "TextView", so it is a strong hint that this was a problem with a TextView.